# Tracking a conversion funnel that changes subdomains

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to set up Google Analytics (Universal/analytics.js) to track a user account set-up funnel on a single website with many subdomains. On each subdomain, a user can express interest in creating an account, and then create the account. Once the account is created, they leave the subdomain and arrive on the main domain.

For the subdomain `foo`, the flow is like this:

1. foo.maindomain.com - register interest
2. foo.maindomain.com/inv/acc0unTt0k3n - enter account set-up details
3. maindomain.com/extra_information - info is supplied
4. maindomain.com/home - goal end point reached

I have set up a View for each subdomain e.g 'Viewing foo.maindomain.com', and each View has a Filter that accurately shows visits to `foo.maindomain.com` & `foo.maindomain.com/inv/acc0unTt0k3n`.

I don't know how to go about tracking traffic through this whole funnel. My ideal end-goal would be to track this funnel for all subdomains combined, but I would be satisfied for now with getting a Goal or Funnel that worked for each subdomain individually.

Inside my 'Viewing foo.maindomain.com' View, I have attempted to create a Goal to track this. I can capture the first two steps by creating:

```
 Goal Type > Destination
 Destination: /inv/
 Funnel: /
```

This gives a 20% conversion rate, which matches up with my server data for account creations. But if I try to change the Destination to maindomain.com/boarding, and add /inv/ as another step in the Funnel, it no longer works ("Verify this Goal" returns 0).

How can I create a Goal that captures all of these steps?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using the same UA code on every subdomain.

You should then just be able to see all the subdomains in the standard view out of the box - UA tracks across subdomains automatically. [See the Google documentation for details](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain)

You don't need to set up a view for each subdomain if you don't need it.

Name your master View "Rollup" if you like.

You can see all subdomains in your "Hostname" report for that view.

You may want to overwrite your pageview names so they also incude the subdomain, so you can tell them apart (if say subdomain1.domain.com/index.html and subdomain2.domain.com/index.html exist, in the standard pagetracking they will be aggregated)  - this can be done via filters:

```
Filter Type: Custom filter > Advanced
Field A: Hostname Extract A: (.*)
Field B: Request URI Extract: (.*)
Output To: Request URI Constructor: $A1$B1
```